# Calling resultsets from a storedproc

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using SQL 2000. I have a stored proc, `spGetApplicantList`, which cannot be modified. I need to get the unique `LastNameInitials` of all the records in that stored proc, so the list of applicants can be sorted alphabetically.

Basically what I need is

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(LastName, 1) as [LastNameInitial]
FROM spGetApplicantList
ORDER BY LastnameFirstInitial
```

How can I create a new stored proc, `spGetLastNameInitial`, by using the recordset returned from `spGetApplicantList`?

I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to execute the first sproc spGetApplicantList into a temp table, and then query that. You can't call stored procedures inline in SELECT statements like that unfortunately.

```
-- Create temp table, with the schema matching the results of spGetApplicantList 
CREATE TABLE #TempResults
(
LastName VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT #TempResults
EXECUTE spGetApplicantList

Select DISTINCT LEFT(LastName, 1) as [LastNameInitial] from #TempResults Order by LastnameFirstInitial

DROP TABLE #TempResults
```

The alternative, is you duplicate the SELECT from the original stored procedure but just do the DISTINCT instead of returning the full resultset - that would save you having to load all the data into a temp table.

Comment: I am trying out your code, but get a "Server: Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Procedure spGetApplicantList , Line 371
Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

Comment: You need to make sure the #TempResults table is defined with the exact same columns as spGetApplicantList returns. As I don't know what columns/data types that sproc returns, I just gave a basic example assuming it only returned a single "LastName" column of type VARCHAR(50)

Comment: So I guess its not possible to insert only LastName column into the temp table? I have to mirror the temp table to reflect the columns in spGetApplicantList?

Comment: Correct - there's no way round that with stored procedures. Hence, it's a last resort in my book, especially if the sproc returns a large amount of records

Answer (score 0):

This is from this link:
[Calling SP from SP](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/generic/0,295582,sid87_gci1207164,00.html#9)

9. How can I use results from one stored procedure in another?

So long as the stored procedure produces only a single result, the technique for using the output of one stored procedure in another is pretty straightforward. The technique is to use a temporary table to hold the results of the stored procedure and an INSERT EXEC statement to execute the sproc and save the results. Once the results are in the temporary table they can be used like any other table data. Here's an example procedure that we might like to reuse:

CREATE PROC  usp_Demo_AllAuthors as

```
select * from pubs..authors
```

GO

Now here's a stored procedure that uses the results of usp_Demo_AllAuthors:

CREATE proc usp_Demo_SPUser as

```
CREATE TABLE #Authors (
 au_id varchar(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
 au_lname varchar (40) NOT NULL ,
 au_fname varchar (20) NOT NULL ,
 phone char (12) NOT NULL,
 address varchar (40) NULL ,
 city varchar (20) NULL ,
 state char (2) NULL ,
 zip char (5) NULL ,
 contract bit NOT NULL
)

-- Execute usp_Demo_AllAuthors storing the
-- results in #Authors
insert into #Authors
 exec usp_Demo_AllAuthors

-- Here we use the #Authors table.  This example only
-- only selects from the temp table but you could do much
-- more such as use a cursor on the table or join with 
-- other data.
SELECT au_fName + ' ' + au_lname as [name]
     , address+', '+city+', '+state+' '+zip [Addr] 
    from #Authors

DROP TABLE #Authors
```

GO

—Andrew Novick, SQL Server Expert